# Compare 4 columns in one excel sheet using vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I need your help please, I have 4 columns in an excel sheet and I need to compare them 2 by 2 i will explain to you :

In column A i have users(user1,user2,user3 ...)
In column B i have functionalities ( fonc1, fonc2, fonc3.....)

In column C i have users(user1,user2,user3 ...)
In column D i have functionalities ( fonc1, fonc2, fonc3.....)

The columns C and D are a new version of columns A and B in the columns C and D the users may change order or change functionalities .

When i execute my code i put the result in other new columns:
column F where i have the users 
column G where i put the  Deleted_functionalities
column H where i put the New_functionalities

The first problem is that the code doesn't get the users it get only the new and deleted functionalities. The second problem is that when the column A is more than column C where the users are stocked the code doesn't work. Can you please help me to find a solution? Thank you in advance .
Here is my code and the file I am working on :

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
  Dim rngCell As Range
    For Each rngCell In Range("B2:B2000")
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("D2:D2000"), rngCell) = 0 Then
            Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = rngCell
        End If
    Next
    For Each rngCell In Range("D2:D2000")
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B2:B2000"), rngCell) = 0 Then
            Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = rngCell
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

and this is the excel file 
http://www.cjoint.com/c/FCxnwjp22rv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range, funcCell As Range
Dim oldUserRng As Range, newUserRng As Range, reportRng As Range
Dim iReport As Long
Dim oldFunc As String, newFunc As String

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("users") '<== adapt it to your needs
With ws
    Set oldUserRng = .Columns(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
    Set newUserRng = .Columns(3).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
    Set reportRng = .Range("F1:I1") '<== added one report column to account for unchanged functions
End With

reportRng.Value = Array("user", "deleted", "new", "same")
iReport = 1
For Each cell In oldUserRng
    With cell
        oldFunc = .Offset(, 1).Value
        Set funcCell = FindAndOffset(newUserRng, .Value, 1)
        If funcCell Is Nothing Then
            reportRng.Offset(iReport) = Array(.Value, "", "", oldFunc)
        Else
            newFunc = funcCell.Value
            If newFunc = oldFunc Then
                reportRng.Offset(iReport) = Array(.Value, "", "", newFunc)
            Else
                reportRng.Offset(iReport) = Array(.Value, oldFunc, newFunc, "")
            End If
        End If
        iReport = iReport + 1
    End With
Next cell

For Each cell In newUserRng
    With cell
        Set funcCell = FindAndOffset(oldUserRng, .Value, 1)
        If funcCell Is Nothing Then
            reportRng.Offset(iReport) = Array(.Value, "", .Offset(, 1).Value, "")
            iReport = iReport + 1
        End If
    End With
Next cell

End Sub
```

Not so sure it does what you need.
you'd better provide screenshots of "before" and "after" scenarios.
BTW, is it safe to assume that both old and new user columns cannot hold duplicates (i.e.: two or more "userX" in column A and/or column C?)

But it does speed up thing considerably since it iterates only through non empty cells.

Comment: thank you i have updated the code for my needs and it works halalouya lool thank you again

Answer (score 0):

I hope I get what you want to achieve. Does the following solve your problem?

```
 Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
  Dim rngCell As Range
    For Each rngCell In Range("A2:A20000")
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C2:C20000"), rngCell) > 0 Then
            Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = rngCell
            Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) = rngCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rngCell.Value, Range("C2:D20000"), 2, 0)
        ElseIf (rngCell <> "") Then

            Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = rngCell
            Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) = rngCell.Offset(0, 1).Value

        End If
    Next

    For Each rngCell In Range("C2:C20000")
        If (WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A2:A20000"), rngCell) = 0 And rngCell <> "") Then
              Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = rngCell
              Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2) = rngCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End If
    Next


End Sub
```

A user is only included in column F when he appears both in columns A and C.In case you want to include every user that is either in column A or C the code has to be altered.

Comment: first of all thank you for responding to my question :)

Comment: the code that you gave me is working geat with the deleted functionalities , but not with the new functionalities  for exemple in the excel file that i puted in the user_v2 we have a user4 wich didn't exist in user_v1 but when i run the code i dont find him in the results , do you have any idea on how to solve this , thank you in advance

Comment: So you want to include every user in column F, even if he only is in either column A or column C?

Comment: like if we have user in column C  but he do not exist in column A he will be puted directly user  and his functionality will be puted as new functionality !! is there a way to do this ?

Comment: I changed the code, hope it is working now! Can a single user appear several times in one column?

Comment: Okay, then the above code should work? Or are you still encountering any problems?

Comment: thank you very much for your effort , still have just one more thing , a little problem  is that now in the column new functionalities its not what it should be showing for example  for user1 in column A it has Fonc2 in column C it has Fonc6 so Fonc6 is the new functionality but it does not apear in the column H what can be done for this ??

Comment: I thought there are user names in column C once again and the new functionalities are in column D? If your table is set up this way I am afraid I can't help you any further because for me the code works just as it is supposed to, showing the new functionality in column H.

Comment: yes yes the only thing is that the functionalities that exist in column D but do not exist in column B goes to the column H with their user ? is that doable ??

Comment: But isn't that already done by the code? All functionalities from column D are in column H.

Comment: unfortunately no :( i don't know how to fix it